# Load a Web Page in Flex component

Tags: html, apache-flex, dataprovider

Is there a way to display a web page in a flex component like Canvas, Hbox or TextArea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Flex IFRAME](http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/) that embeds HTML Browsing in Flex apps.

Answer (score 0):

There is some good stuff [in here](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/html_and_flex_1.html) about mixing Flex and HTML.  In fact it is a great Flex blog altogether.