# How can I embed a web page in Adobe Flash Builder? (FLEX)

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I want to embed a web page in Flash (Adobe Flash Builder) using the basic knowledge. I mean I want my app to be able to use the 3D structure, spinning it etc... and I heard that I can use a view where I can put a URL-link or something so it would appear like it's in the app.

About the web page it's something like this (the 3D viewer embed of this https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model.html?id=4ceb45eacc729c5ea611269c93d910)

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load a Web Page in Flex component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947515/load-a-web-page-in-flex-component)

Comment: Also possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408009/open-a-web-page-in-a-flex-mobile-app and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144013/display-and-navigate-a-web-page-from-a-flex-tab